# HTML autoplay not working in Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari, autoplay

My aim is to autoplay a song on a website in Chrome and Safari, but it is not working. I found a trick to use an `iframe` with a silence.mp3 before playing the `audio` tag, but it also did not work.

My code:

```
<iframe src="silence.mp3" allow="autoplay" id="audio" style="display: none" type="audio/mp3"></iframe>
<div style="position: fixed; left: 0px;top: 0px;">
      <audio id="vid" controls loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" type="audio/mp3">
           <source src="song.mp3">
           Your browser does not support the audio element.
      </audio>
</div>
```

Is there anything I can do about that?

Answer (score 0):

You cant - User interaction is needed to allow play/autoplay media with sound.

Add `muted` attribute

```
<audio id="vid" controls loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" type="audio/mp3" muted>
...
</audio>
```

Audio will start to play only without the sound. Then allow user to switch sound on with JS.

**EDIT**

It seems that this is no longer working with audio tag

Tested with video

```html
<video controls muted autoplay>
        <source src="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-13.mp3"/>
</video>
```

Comment: How is this working with JS? Do you have a tutorial link or something?

Comment: I also tried to add ´muted´ but it still is not autoplayed

Comment: w3schools provides good tutorials about web technologies. You have basic example of autoplay property : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_audio_autoplay.asp